# How do i write a Method in C#, that returns once a condition is true?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have a method where i want to return Task and the task finish once some internal condition is true.
so the code would be:

```
public Task<Result> Method(int numberOfAggregats){
    return new Task<Result>(() => "return result once 
                aggregated information > numberOfAggregates");
}
```

Is there some way to do this without a loop that eats all the cpu or a Thread.Sleep?

some more information: i have a class who´s purpose is to aggregate information coming in through wcf queries into the server. this is the class containing the "Method" method.
this method is beeing called by the ui, as well as background works, who need the aggregated information.

until now we were passing in a callback action into method, which would be called once all the information was there. The idea behind returning Task is to get rid of the callbacks, since they complicate the code in the depending modules.

Comment: That's pretty vague, do you control the condition? Sometimes it's the only way, that is if it's out of your control and you have no idea when it's going to happen. Other than then you should really try avoiding those cases

Comment: yes i have control over the condition. the condition variable is in the same class. the problem is that i have no idea how long it will take for the condition to become true, since its beeing set from a different thread. it could take anywhere from a second to 10 minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx):

`System.Threading.AutoResetEvent _notifier = new AutoResetEvent(false);`

- At the waiting task call `_notifier.WaitOne();` so it will blocked until receive a signal.
- When *internal condition* becomes true call `_notifier.Set();` to signal the waiting task to finish.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.wait.aspx
Try this it's a conditional variable lock. Once the task is done you can signal the variable and that will begin execution.

Comment: mhh i thought about it, and it would fit really nicely normaly. the problem is that the condition will usually not be set to true by the same thread that entered the method. as far as i understand, leaving the monitor would constrain me to seting the condition in the same thread that entered the method the first time

Comment: mhh then i dont understand what you mean. wouldnt you just say: monitor.enter(conditionWaiter) in the Method and call Monitor.Wait(conditionWaiter) in the task. now to exiting the monitor would have to be done in the same thread as entering it, unless i´m very mistaken

Comment: you can do lock(not_done_yet) { do work } then once it leaves the lock block your Monitor.wait(not_done_yet) will release and return.

Comment: ah i see what you mean. the problem is that i cant finish the work inside a block, since its actually coming in over the network and is usually only finished after more then one call

Comment: you can use Monitor.Enter and Monitor.Exit once your code is done which is essentially what a lock block does

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the [IAsynchResult pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx) is what you're looking for

However since you're using the TPL a [continuation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288.aspx) might make more sense